# How to make diagram of project activity by weeks in oracle xe112?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a SQL code for making a diagram of project activity by days.

```
select d.*, count(rb.action) actions from
(select ((trunc(to_date('2014-01-26','YYYY-MM-DD'),'MONTH'))+level) dday from dual connect by level <= 30) d
left join revisions rv on (d.dday = rv.rdate)
left join revision_body rb on (rb.revision_id = rv.revision_id)
group by d.dday
order by d.dday;
```

However, I need to get counting by weeks in this month. For that I tried to write this query

```
    select 'WEEK '|| row_number() over(order by trunc(to_date(substr(rv.rdate,1,10), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'IW')) WEEK, count(rb.action) actions from revisions rv
where trunc(to_date(substr(rv.rdate,1,10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '31-JAN-14'
    left join revision_body rb on (rb.revision_id = rv.revision_id) 
    group by trunc(to_date(substr(rv.rdate,1,10), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'IW')) 
    order by trunc(to_date(substr(rv.rdate,1,10), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'IW'));
```

but I have an error:`"SQL command not properly ended"` in the 4th line. Why isn't it ended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this corrected query. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27d04/1)

```
select 'WEEK '|| row_number() over(order by trunc(rv.rdate, 'IW')) WEEK, 
    count(rb.action) actions 
  from revisions rv left join revision_body rb using (revision_id) 
  where trunc(rv.rdate) BETWEEN date '2014-01-01' AND date '2014-01-31'
  group by trunc(rv.rdate, 'IW') order by trunc(rv.rdate, 'IW');
```

In your query you put `left join` in wrong place, conditions for dates were not correct, and some brackets were missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your `WHERE` clause must follow the `LEFT JOIN` keyword.

I mean:

```
select 'WEEK '|| row_number() over(order by trunc(to_date(substr(rb.rdate,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'), 'IW')) WEEK, count(rb.action) actions from revisions rv
    left join revision_body rb on (rb.revision_id = rv.revision_id) 
where trunc(to_date(substr(rb.rdate,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '31-JAN-14'
    group by trunc(to_date(substr(rb.rdate,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'), 'IW')) 
    order by trunc(to_date(substr(rb.rdate,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'), 'IW'));
```